# iOS CoreData parsing from CSV cannot save error 1570 nil object

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm quite new to objective c and iOS, would really appreciate some help here.
I have been banging my head against the wall trying to get this working, but keep getting the error:

```
Failed to save to data store: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1570.)
```

What I am doing is importing a CSV file.

From what I can tell it is partially working. CSV is correctly being parsed, I'm getting all the correct values, and I have debugged through and from what I can tell the KA objects are all getting the right values.

But there seems to be something wrong with how I am doing the relationships - **the 1570 issue is coming from a nil newTrainingDay's required date field** (which seems like it is filled from when I've debugged). I have a feeling something else is wrong but I am not sure what..

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: If you inspect newTrainingDay.date immediately after the line newTrainingDay.date = date; is executed, is its value good at that point?  Also, what about other fields in the same NSManagedObject?  That is, if you look at the entire managed object all fields appear to be completed?

Comment: Yep it is a good value that is the odd part of this. It seems to be happening ( I  think ) when I do the `newTrainingDay = day;` - as the error does not shoot out on the first of each training day (the one where date is actually set)

Comment: Another strange thing going on - the data isn't being set, but I am displaying from the context in a view controller, which shows, but only the last day shows - however there are two days in the csv (each day has multiple sets in the format like top of the post)

Comment: Does this look like a possibility (I didn't really follow what you were doing with the fetches above the offending code).  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666178/multi-context-coredata-with-threads

This is where there are multiple contexts at work, though.

Comment: well that's interesting sounds exactly like what is happening. I am not using multiple contexts though.

Comment: About a month ago I was working on a class that would import a sqlite file into my core data context.  I had what looked like an identical problem and was stuck on it for a couple days.  But I cannot remember what the problem was.  I've been looking back at that class trying to figure out what I ended up doing about it.  I'll look some more.  It is driving me nuts I can't remember that after spending so much time on.  One of the downsides of being an old man I guess ;)

Comment: haha well I'm by no means old yet catch myself doing the same - seems like my brain is project oriented - once I move to another topic a lot of the old gets pushed out! Would be grateful to hear if you come up with anything! Only thing I can think of is something is going wrong with the context for some reason. Going to look into whether I've set something up wrong. Side note - I have it set up in AppDelegate; how did you end up setting yours up?

Comment: Along those lines -- and I've been looking and can't find it -- but when I had this problem I came across a post on SO having to do with the refreshing when a predicate is changed.  So, if you run one predicate then make some changes to the fetched result, then, set a different predicate that selected different objects, there was some sort of issue with the caching.  Someone had linked to the Apple docs or something and indicated it was as designed.  It wasn't on-point with my problem, but I remember seeing it.  I can't find it now, and don't know whether that could be related to your issue.

Comment: I have a sort of helper class that I use for core data access generally, and I had a separate class to handle the import.  The import class created a separate core data stack for the sqlite table I was importing and would read from that and copy it to my main database.  I don't think it would have mattered if it were in AppDelegate, but in my case the import was a small part of the overall app so I'm just trying to keep AppDelegate as clean as possible.

Comment: Yeah I like the idea of moving it out into a helper class for the import. I was thinking to make a little helper command line app that ships with the app to take care of the import. AppDelegate looks too cluttered with all this in there. Thanks for the help! Seems it was just a silly error of inserting before fetching 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem stems from creating and inserting new objects into the database, before then searching to see if there is an existing object that meets your needs.  Take this code, for example:

```
 // look for existing day
    KATrainingDay *newTrainingDay = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"KATrainingDay" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    // Fetching
    fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"KATrainingDay"];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date == %@", date]];
    // Execute Fetch Request
    fetchError = nil;
    NSArray *trainingDays = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&fetchError];
    // if you found it
    if (!fetchError) {
        if ([trainingDays count]) {
            for (KATrainingDay *day in trainingDays) {
                newTrainingDay = day;
            }
        } else {
            // set name and date for training day
            newTrainingDay.date = date;
            newTrainingDay.name = trainingDayNameString;
            [newTrainingDay addRoutinesObject:newTrainingRoutine];
            [newTrainingRoutine addTrainingDaysObject:newTrainingDay];
        }
```

You start by creating and inserting a `KATrainingDay` into your context, and then do a fetch to look for a `KATrainingDay` with the right date.  If you find it, you assign your pointer (`newTrainingDay`) to the object you just fetched.  **But the object you just inserted is still in the context (though you no longer have a pointer to it) and will have nil values for all its attributes and relationships.** Hence when you save, that object fails the required day constraint.

To fix this, insert new objects only if you don't find a match with your fetch:

```
 // look for existing day
    KATrainingDay *newTrainingDay;
    // Fetching
    fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"KATrainingDay"];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date == %@", date]];
    // Execute Fetch Request
    fetchError = nil;
    NSArray *trainingDays = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&fetchError];
    // if you found it
    if (!fetchError) {
        if ([trainingDays count]) {
            for (KATrainingDay *day in trainingDays) {
                newTrainingDay = day;
            }
        } else {
            // set name and date for training day
            newTrainingDay = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"KATrainingDay" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]
            newTrainingDay.date = date;
            newTrainingDay.name = trainingDayNameString;
        } 
        [newTrainingDay addRoutinesObject:newTrainingRoutine];
```

(and likewise for the other entities).  In the above I have also moved the `addRoutinesObject:` call outside that else block, so it will execute whether you find existing or create new (which I assume you want).  And note you don't need to set both sides of the relationship - if you set one side, CoreData does the other for you automatically (assuming they are defined as inverses).  One other tip, you don't need your for loop to get the last item in an array, you can just use:

```
newTrainingDay = [trainingDays lastObject];
```

Comment: beautiful. Thank you for catching that. I actually tried something along those lines but was doing `KATrainingDay *newTrainingDay = [[KATrainingDay alloc] init];` rather than just creating a pointer to nowhere. Obviously that does not work with `NSManagedObject`s. Yeah I suppose I could use `firstObject` or `lastObject` rather than looping since there should only be one in each of these fetches. Good point. Thank you!